# Data Formatters temporarily Unavailable, will re-try after a continue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am working on Objective C to develop an app in I Pad. When I run the program its getting executed in Simulator of IPad. When I do the same connecting the device then I am facing an Error as GDB:Data Formatters temporarily unavailable,will re-try after a 'continue'.
Someone guide how to solve this issue.

Regards,
Vani.

Answer (score 0):

This can be because of several reasons:

1. Memory issue. Try running your app with instruments to check
2. When it is unable to find a linked in shared library at launch time.
3. Also you can try running in a different target xcode and check if that works
4. Check all you breakpoints. In the Debugger window, click on "Show Breakpoints" and see if there are any unusually placed breakpoints

Comment: I think the first reason might be the issue. But I have deleted all the unnecessary declartions. Now my code is clean. I am unable to solve this Memory Issue. Can you help me where i might be going wrong.

Comment: Try running it with instruments "leak"

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same problem in cocoa application.
Take a look at [Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'.](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/7314)

> "Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a
>   'continue'." means that something has gone so horribly wrong in your
>   code that even the debugger bailed. As [dragyn](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/profile/13820) said, this usually
>   involves some form of rapid object creation or recursion calling. Add
>   a few NSLog lines into your code to help you see how far your code is
>   getting and where it might be looping/calling itself.